# How do I return a generic Readable object from a Sqlite Query?

Tags: c#, sqlite, generics

I am using a query to query my Sqlite database like so:

```
string noteSql = "select Column1, Column2 from [Diary.Notes]"

var notes = database.Query<object>(noteSql) as List<Object>;
```

Where `Column1` is an `Int` and `Column2` is a `String`

But when my list `notes` is returned the objects are unreadable.

I know I can make an object with two properties of type `Int` and `String` which would work for my two columns returned from `[DiaryNotes]` but I would like a more generic solution.

I have tried to make a generic class like the following:

```
[Table("Table1")]
public class GenericSqliteObject : Object
{
    public GenericSqliteObject()
    {

    }

    private object _column1;
    [Column("Column1")]
    public object Column1
    {
        get { return _column1; }
        set { _column1 = value; }
    }


    private object _column2;
    [Column("Column2")]
    public object Column2
    {
        get { return _column2; }
        set { _column2 = value; }
    }

}
```

but changing the line to:

```
var notes = database.Query<GenericSqliteObject>(noteSql) as List<GenericSqliteObject>;
```

Keeps returning the error:

> {System.NotSupportedException: Don't know how to read System.Object
>   at SQLite.Net.SQLiteCommand.ReadCol (IDbStatement stmt, Int32 index,
>   ColType type, System.Type clrType) [0x00827] in :0
>   at SQLite.Net.SQLiteCommand+d__15`1[T].MoveNext
>   () [0x00137] in :0

Is there a way to return a generic object from a Sqlite query so that I do not have to create objects for different use cases?

PS. my example here has been simplified to demonstrate the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my solution was to save all the Column values as strings and parse them at runtime.

Therefore my `GenericSqliteObject` looks like the following:

```
namespace FieldStrikeMove.PortableData.Helpers
{
    [Table("Table1")]
    public class GenericSqliteObject : Object
    {
        public GenericSqliteObject()
        {

        }

        private string _column1;
        [Column("Column1")]
        public string Column1
        {
            get { return _column1; }
            set { _column1 = value; }
        }


        private string _column2;
        [Column("Column2")]
        public string Column2
        {
            get { return _column2; }
            set { _column2 = value; }
        }


        public int? GetInt(string column)
        {
            int rint;

            if (Int32.TryParse(column, out rint))
                return rint;
            else
                return null;
        }

        public long? GetLong(string column)
        {
            long rlong;

            if (Int64.TryParse(column, out rlong))
                return rlong;
            else
                return null;
        }

        public bool? GetBool(string column)
        {
            bool rbool;

            if (Boolean.TryParse(column, out rbool))
                return rbool;
            else
                return null;
        }
        public double? GetDouble(string column)
        {
            double rdouble;

            if (Double.TryParse(column, out rdouble))
                return rdouble;
            else
                return null;
        }
        public float? GetFloat(string column)
        {
            float rfloat;

            if (float.TryParse(column, out rfloat))
                return rfloat;
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And you can add any extra `Get` methods to this that you need